# Not able to type anything in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, jetbrains-ide

I have updated Android Studio to 3.4 and since then not able to type anything in My IDE. I can see words are getting printed on editor but on a very next second they are getting erased and cursor stays at same location. Though I am able to perform Copy Paste.

This is very annoying and giving me huge break in my work.

Comment: First try a clean reinstall of Android Studio. Get back to me if it works.

Comment: @SnakeException It worked. I did clean reinstall and everything is working fine now.

Comment: please see my answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a clean reinstall of Android Studio. It has solved my problem many times and should work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Press the insert key, that could be it.

Comment: clean re-installation suggested by @SnakeException above did resolve the issue.